# Set background color of TextBox if ReadOnly

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, textbox

When a TextBox in Silverlight 5 is set to `ReadOnly = true`, the background turns gray.

I need it to remain White.

The TextBox is Enabled but set to read only. It mus be readonly.

Is there a way to make the Background of the TextBox any color when  in read only mode ?

I have attempted to extend the control like this:

```
public partial class MyTextBox: TextBox
{

    private Brush highlightBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    private Brush forgoundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    private Brush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    public BulletListItem()
    {
        this.applyStyle();
    }


    private void applyStyle()
    {
        this.FontSize = 26;
        this.Foreground =forgoundBrush;
        this.IsEnabled = true;
        this.IsReadOnly = true;
        this.BorderBrush = backgroundBrush;
        this.Background = backgroundBrush;
        this.SelectionBackground = backgroundBrush;
        this.TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I found a hack to do this, I would still appreciate if someone has a better solution but here is how I did it.

1. Edit the Silverlight program in Blend
2. Right click on the TextBox and Edit Style (Create Copy)
3. Save and Open Visual Studio again
4. Find the Style from the created Template supplied by Blend.
5. Find the line of code that has

`<Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="#5EC9C9C9" Opacity="0"/>`

and Replace with

`<Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="White" Opacity="0"/>`

Comment: No i think the way you found is the only way to do it, as you're overriding the default silverlight style for a textbox with your own custom one

Comment: Thanks, Im completely new to Silverlight coming from WinForms so thank-you for confirming my approach.